# Issue with css { direction: rtl }

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I made example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6CRc7/2/ I am trying to make timer from other side. But direction: rtl; doesnt work dir="rtl" also.

Comment: What do you mean by "make timer from other side"? Do you actually intend to make it read right-to-left as in ss-mm-hh-dd?

Comment: why not reverse manually your <span>s and your displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `float` in `.countdown_section` is what controlling the order of the fields, so if you'll change it value to `right` you'd get it as ss:mmm:hh:dd, but keep in mind that while RTL text is written from right to left, numbers, are written from left to right as you'd expect from regular latin content.

Answer (score 0):

I think there maybe some confusion about the purpose of direction: rtl, as I am aware this only applies to text in a div, used to display languages such as arabic which read from right to left, I think you are just trying to arrange your span tags in reverse order so it displays seconds, mins, hours? Or have i misinterpreted your question?

See here for a basic example... http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction

Comment: You will get downvoted, remove the w3schools link from your answer please.

Comment: Indeed. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction would be a much more thorough reference.

Comment: Sure thing, link changed as requested, apologies for any foul, im relatively new to 'the stack'